# How do I know which child keys are expected for parent key In kubernetes yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I've just started learning about kubernetes and yaml files.

Although kubernetes documentation provides lot's of examples.

One thing I couldn't manage to find were how the different **Kind** (Deployment, Pod, Service, ConfigMap, Etc...) required a different yaml structure and keys.

So i would like to know, how do i find out what are all the child keys that a given parent key expect to have, and the data type a key expect, in case of expecting a list of something for example.

I really would appreciate some help with that , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[It's documented on the Kubernetes website.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/) However it may be a bit cumbersome to learn it like this, and you may prefer to learn mostly by looking at examples and existing yaml files.

Also, a good IDE that support Kubernetes can help you writing the files.

Comment: It's not quite that what I'm looking for althought it partially answers my question. What i want specifically is a way to know which child keys are allowed inside a spec key por example. If you could help me with i would be really thankful